# how to deny downloading file in nginx coming via php file

Tags: nginx

In moodle the files are downloaded via plugin.php such as 
/pluginfile.php?forcedownload=1&file=%2F12489%2Fbackup%2Fautomated%2Fbackup-moodle2-course-31-rnq-20190623-0710.mbz

i want to deny all download of *.mbz did the following but nothing works

location ~* .(mbz|git|rb|inc|ht)$ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ (.mbz$) {
    return 403;
}

location ~* .mbz$ {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

Comment: To clarify, file downloads are initially started with PHP but you want to deny them at a server level with Nginx?

Comment: yes  i want to block it on nginx level